# How to reference an assembly(*.dll) without visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

## Goal

I'm trying to use a dll file in a c# project. I know how to it with visual studio but is there any other way (without visual studio)?
When I add dll file as reference into console app with visual studio, it does not add anything to Program.cs, But I think something should be added to it (and Program.cs of dll file I guess) when you don't want to use visual studio. For example what should I do when I want to use the following dll file:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public static int Sum(int x, int y)
        {
            int a = x;
            int b = y;
            int result = a + b;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

in the following Console App:

```cs
using System;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Class1.Sum(1, 40));
        }
    }
}
```

## Edit

I mean what does visual studio to add a reference to project? (I want to do it without Visual Studio).

Comment: You totally confuse two different DLL types: native DLLs created with C and managed (.NET) dlls created with C#. Two first directives are for loading native DLLs but then you have an example of a managed DLL.

Comment: How are you compiling? Do you have a project file? If you have a project file, you can add references in the project file. If you are just trying to have multiple code files, you need a project.

Comment: @WiktorZychla Thanks! edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the DLL reference into the csproj file.

Like (new csproj file format):

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\*.dll" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

This method will load the dll as below-

```
var DLL=Assembly.LoadFile(YourfilePath)
```

Comment: Pls follow the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928528/dynamically-load-a-dll-from-a-specific-folder